# how to turn off verbose reporting by htmlunit?

Tags: htmlunit

htmlunit reports everything from css, to parsing errors on a page.

how to silence this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTMLUnit uses Apache commons logging which delegates actual logging to a "real" logging framework, or the standard java one.

If your application uses log4j you can use that to reduce the chattiness of htmlunit.

More details can be found on the [logging page of the docs](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/logging.html)

Answer (score 6):

Put these after declaring webClient

```
            webClient.setCssErrorHandler(new SilentCssErrorHandler());
            LogFactory.getFactory().setAttribute("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit").setLevel(Level.OFF);
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.commons.httpclient").setLevel(Level.OFF);
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter").setLevel(Level.OFF);
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.ActiveXObject").setLevel(Level.OFF);
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.html.HTMLDocument").setLevel(Level.OFF);
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript").setLevel(Level.OFF);
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.WindowProxy").setLevel(Level.OFF);
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache").setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

Answer (score 0):

HTMLUnit uses standard JAVA logger.

To disable it include the following line in your code.

```
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(Level.OFF);
```